# SPA with asp.net mvc 3 (Sample application)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Can anybody point me to a sample SPA application (source code) that is constructed using asp.net mvc 3, knockout or whatever, partial views (potentially) ?

I am looking for a well architected code so that I can wrap my head around how SPA works.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a well attached code you need to ask a specific question.

The best answer for what you asked would be this: http://www.asp.net/single-page-application